# How to Expression.Invoke an arbitrary LINQ to SQL Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Say I take an arbitrary [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL_.28formerly_called_DLINQ.29) query's *Expression*, is it possible to invoke it somehow?

```
MyContext ctx1 = new MyContext("...");
var q = from t in ctx1.table1 where t.id = 1 select t;
Expression qe = q.Expression;
var res = Expression.Invoke(qe);
```

This throws:

> ArgumentException "Expression of type System.Linq.IQueryable`1[...]' cannot be invoked".

My ultimate goal is to evaluate the same query on several different data contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Queries are not Expressions.  A Query has an ExpressionTree.

Queries are not Methods to be invoked.

Queries may be Enumerated, yielding their results.  This code will Enumerate any IQueryable:

```
List<object> result = query.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

---

> My ultimate goal is to evaluate the
>   same query on several different data
>   contexts.

Then you should write your queries as query generators, that accept DataContext as a parameter.

```
Func<MyDataContext, IQueryable<Customer>> queryGen =
    (dc) => dc.Customers.Where(c => c.Name == "Bob");
  //now we can get some queries
IQueryable<Customer> query1 = queryGen(new MyDataContext());
IQueryable<Customer> query2 = queryGen(new MyDataContext());
```

Comment: Are you claiming the property IQueryable.Expression  does not exists? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.expression.aspx

Comment: Accessing a query's Expression in order to tamper with the DataContext is like disassembling your car engine in order to turn on the radio.

Answer (score 0):

[LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL_.28formerly_called_DLINQ.29) expressions are parsed by the LINQ to SQL Provider and converted into [T-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL). My guess is that exception is being raised explicitly - that Microsoft did not intend for those expressions to be Invoked directly (you could confirm this using [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector).)

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to run an Expression across different contexts, why not create just the expression like so:-

```
    Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> myExpression = x => x.id == 1;
```

Then you can do whatever you like with it, including using it in .Where() clauses.

Comment: A query is way more than a WHERE clause. I want *arbitrary* queries.